# Query optimisation on large join

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-11

**(pg version 11.2)**

I have the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE site_tally
(
    id               serial,
    dt_created       timestamp WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    dt_updated       timestamp WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    geo              text                                      NOT NULL,
    dt_tally         date                                      NOT NULL,
    parent_site      text                                      NOT NULL,
    site_id          integer                                   NOT NULL,
    tracked          boolean                                   NOT NULL,
    utm_parameter_id integer                                   NOT NULL,
    device           text                                      NOT NULL,
    layout_id        integer                                   NOT NULL,
    views            integer                     DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, geo)
) PARTITION BY LIST (geo);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX site_tally_uindex
    ON site_tally (geo, dt_tally, parent_site, site_id, tracked, utm_parameter_id, device, layout_id);

CREATE TABLE site_tally_uk PARTITION OF site_tally FOR VALUES IN ('UK');
CREATE TABLE site_tally_us PARTITION OF site_tally FOR VALUES IN ('US');
CREATE TABLE site_tally_au PARTITION OF site_tally FOR VALUES IN ('AU');


CREATE TABLE utm_parameters
(
    id         serial                            NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    dt_created timestamp DEFAULT now()           NOT NULL,
    source     text      DEFAULT 'default'::text NOT NULL,
    medium     text      DEFAULT 'default'::text NOT NULL,
    campaign   text      DEFAULT 'default'::text NOT NULL,
    term       text      DEFAULT 'default'::text NOT NULL,
    content    text      DEFAULT 'default'::text NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX utm_parameters_source_medium_campaign_term_content_uindex
    ON utm_parameters (source, medium, campaign, term, content);
```

`site_tally` was specifically partitioned for performance reasons, as we never need to query more than one `geo`.

I am having an edge case scenario where one of our queries is taking very long to run:

```
SELECT SUM(views) AS views,
       term       AS utm
FROM site_tally
         INNER JOIN utm_parameters ON (utm_parameters.id = utm_parameter_id)
WHERE geo = 'UK'
    AND dt_tally >= '2019-08-01'
    AND dt_tally <= '2019-08-31'
    AND parent_site = 'site1'
    AND source = 'source1'
    AND medium = 'medium1'
    AND campaign = 'campaign1'
    AND tracked = FALSE
GROUP BY source,
         medium,
         campaign,
         term;
```

**EXPLAIN ANALYSE:**

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=1.11..12152.56 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=88.064..163032.380 rows=351 loops=1)
"  Group Key: utm_parameters.source, utm_parameters.medium, utm_parameters.campaign, utm_parameters.term"
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.11..12152.53 rows=1 width=70) (actual time=59.993..163025.340 rows=15823 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using utm_parameters_source_medium_campaign_term_content_uindex on utm_parameters  (cost=0.55..8.57 rows=1 width=70) (actual time=0.024..39.883 rows=5994 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((source = 'source1'::text) AND (medium = 'medium1'::text) AND (campaign = 'campaign1'::text))
        ->  Append  (cost=0.56..12143.95 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=26.022..27.188 rows=3 loops=5994)
              ->  Index Scan using site_tally_uk_geo_dt_tally_parent_site_site_id_tracked_utm__idx on site_tally_uk  (cost=0.56..12143.95 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=26.020..27.185 rows=3 loops=5994)
                    Index Cond: ((geo = 'UK'::text) AND (dt_tally >= '2019-08-01'::date) AND (dt_tally <= '2019-08-31'::date) AND (parent_site = 'site1'::text) AND (tracked = false) AND (utm_parameter_id = utm_parameters.id))
                    Filter: (NOT tracked)
Planning Time: 0.693 ms
Execution Time: 163032.762 ms
```

In this particular case, there are many `term` to group by, a query without a `term` behaves very differently:

```
SELECT SUM(views) AS views,
                       campaign   AS utm
                FROM site_tally
                         INNER JOIN utm_parameters ON (utm_parameters.id = utm_parameter_id)
                WHERE geo = 'UK'
                  AND dt_tally >= '2019-08-01'
                  AND dt_tally <= '2019-08-31'
                  AND parent_site = 'site1'
                  AND source = 'source1'
                  AND medium = 'medium1'
                  AND tracked = FALSE
                GROUP BY source,
                         medium,
                         campaign;
```

**EXPLAIN ANALYSE:**

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=87129.06..87129.13 rows=3 width=48) (actual time=54.451..54.451 rows=1 loops=1)
"  Group Key: utm_parameters.source, utm_parameters.medium, utm_parameters.campaign"
  ->  Sort  (cost=87129.06..87129.07 rows=3 width=44) (actual time=50.572..51.398 rows=15823 loops=1)
        Sort Key: utm_parameters.campaign
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2610kB
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=1583.46..87129.04 rows=3 width=44) (actual time=11.359..46.521 rows=15823 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (site_tally_uk.utm_parameter_id = utm_parameters.id)
              ->  Append  (cost=1322.54..86645.61 rows=84764 width=8) (actual time=4.268..31.765 rows=53612 loops=1)
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on site_tally_uk  (cost=1322.54..86221.79 rows=84764 width=8) (actual time=4.267..28.157 rows=53612 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: ((dt_tally <= '2019-08-31'::date) AND (geo = 'UK'::text) AND (dt_tally >= '2019-08-01'::date) AND (parent_site = 'site1'::text) AND (NOT tracked))
                          Heap Blocks: exact=5237
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on site_tally_uk_geo_dt_tally_parent_site_tracked_idx  (cost=0.00..1301.35 rows=84764 width=0) (actual time=3.519..3.519 rows=53612 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (dt_tally <= '2019-08-31'::date)
              ->  Hash  (cost=260.09..260.09 rows=66 width=44) (actual time=7.083..7.084 rows=5994 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 8192 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 556kB
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on utm_parameters  (cost=5.23..260.09 rows=66 width=44) (actual time=1.346..5.862 rows=5994 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: ((source = 'source1'::text) AND (medium = 'medium1'::text))
                          Heap Blocks: exact=2655
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on utm_parameters_source_medium_campaign_term_content_uindex  (cost=0.00..5.21 rows=66 width=0) (actual time=0.991..0.992 rows=5994 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: ((source = 'source1'::text) AND (medium = 'medium1'::text))
Planning Time: 0.571 ms
Execution Time: 54.773 ms
```

**NOTE:** The `site_tally` has a lot more integer based columns (after the  `views` column), these are also used in the SELECT as SUM values. I decided to exclude them from the question as it is already a lengthy one!

So, I would ideally like to speed up this query, I have tried an alternative index strategy:

```
CREATE INDEX testing ON site_tally (geo, dt_tally, parent_site, tracked)
WHERE geo='UK' and dt_tally >= '2019-08-01' and parent_site='site1' and tracked=FALSE;
```

This index does not get picked by the query planner, even when I try to be specific on my queries with something like `dt_tally > '2019-07-31'`.

At this point in time, I am unable to change the unique index on `site_tally` (other queries rely on that specific column order)

I would like to understand what is really happening in this query (I am not too well versed in the EXPLAIN output).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the estimates for the index scan on `utm_parameters` are quite off.

- First, try a simple

  ```
  ANALYZE utm_parameters;
  ```

  and see if that does the trick.
- If that does not improve matters, try gathering more detailed statistics:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE utm_parameters
     ALTER source SET STATISTICS 1000,
     ALTER medium SET STATISTICS 1000,
     ALTER campaign SET STATISTICS 1000;

  ANALYZE utm_parameters;
  ```
- If that also does not improve the estimate, the problem is probably correlation between the columns. Try to create extended statistics:

  ```
  CREATE STATISTICS utm_parameters_stats (dependencies)
     ON source, medium, campaign FROM utm_parameters;

  ANALYZE utm_parameters;
  ```

It seems like the last option did the trick for you. So what happened?

- PostgreSQL has pretty good statistics to estimate the selectivity of conditions of the form `column = value`.
- Let's assume that the selectivity of each of the three conditions is 0.1, that is, 90% of the rows are filtered out. Not knowing any better, PostgreSQL assumes the conditions to be statistically independent, so it assumes that the selectivity of all three conditions together is 0.1 * 0.1 * 0.1 = 0.001.
- Now it happens that the conditions are *not* independent, e.g., if `campaign` is the same for two rows, then `medium` is quite likely also the same for the rows. So PostgreSQL's estimate will be way lower than the reality.
- This low estimate causes PostgreSQL to choose a nested loop join, which is the best access path for small outer tables. But nested loop joins perform pretty badly if the outer table is big. So fixing the estimate improves the performance.

Comment: Very interesting, does this mean it is worth running `ANALYZE utm_parameters;` frequently, in case the table data changes and no longer fits the estimates?

Comment: PostgreSQL does that automatically. If it does not do it often enough, lower `autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor` for that table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198830/discussion-between-joao-and-laurenz-albe).